# Cannot create relationship with multiple child models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

i have three models member, loan and saving. loan and saving being child to member. however, i can only create relationship with loan only.when i create relationship with saving, it deems the function as non static.

Member.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Member extends Model
{
 protected $fillable=['name','address','phone']; 
 public function loan()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Loan::class,'member_id','id');
}
 public  function saving()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Saving::class,'member_id','id');
}
```

}

Saving.php

```
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  class Saving extends Model
  {
  protected $fillable=['amount','member_id']; 
   public function member()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','id','member_id');
    }
```

}

the function saving() gives following error.

```
 Error::Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::saving() non static in class App\Member
```

i have not faced this problem before and lack the core concept.

Comment: The `Model` class already contains a method named `saving`. You have to choose a different name.

Comment: what change do i have  to make to get one to one relation with member - loan. what changes besides using hasOne??

Comment: `HasOne` is the right relationship for this. Does it not work?

Comment: when i change it to hasOne, it gives "trying to get properly of non object" error. i tried swapping keys in which case it gives "invalid data in foreach " error

Comment: Please open a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You provide wrong key in belongsTo relationship , provide like this:

```
public function member()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','member_id','id');
}
```

Comment: i have tried it too. its not working. i swapped key to try hasOne relationship.

Answer (score 1):

In your Model.php change following

```
public function loan()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Loan','member_id','id');
}
 public  function saving()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Saving','member_id','id');
```

Comment: so function saving() is already used by laravel itself... i changed it to function savings(), it worked. thank you both of you.